# Getting Source only and mismatch data with tablediff utility

Tags: sql-server, comparison, data-synchronization

I'm using `tablediff` utility to transfert data from serval databases sources to a destination database and I get a result having all the differences  between the source and destination databases with something like this

```
Dest. Only  N'1027' N'799'  N'91443'    N'1'    
Mismatch    N'103A' N'799'  N'13010'    N'1'    DATE_CURRENT DATE_OPERATION MATRICULE_UTILISATEUR QTE QTE_FINAL QTE_INIT QTE_OPERATION REFERENCE_DOCUMENT TYPE_DOCUMENT 
Src. Only   N'103A' N'310'  N'30129'    N'1'
```

so the generated sql file contain `delete` the `Dest. Only` rows, `update` the `Mismatch` rows and `insert` the `Src. Only` rows

My question is: Is there any way using `tablediff` to get the result of only `Mismatch` and `Src. Only` rows??

Comment: Hi do you still need help with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the end of your `tablediff` tool command add the following

```
-dt -et DiffResults
```

It will drop an existing table with name `DiffResults` and create a new one in the destination server and database.
Then you can query the `DiffResults` table to get the desired rows.
In my test I run the following

```
SELECT * FROM DiffResults
WHERE MSdifftool_ErrorDescription in ('Mismatch','Src. Only')
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM DiffResults
WHERE MSdifftool_ErrorCode in (0,2) -- 0 is for 'Mismatch';  1 is for 'Dest. Only' and 2 is for 'Src. Only'
```

Some more details can be found here - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162843.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use results from command line, you can pipe output with findstr:

```
tablediff <your parameters> | findstr /i "^Mismatch ^Src"
```